# Powershell - Get a List of IIS Applications Vdirectory by Username

Tags: powershell, iis

I run this command to set credentials for a couple of iis applications.

`Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/Webapp']/virtualdirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName=$user;password=$password}`

How can I search for all application paths that uses this username? I want to be able to search by `userName=$user`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to get a list of virtual directories by username.

As far as I know, the "Get-WebVirtualDirectory" does not have a parameter "Filter" like "Set-WebConfiguration". So it is not possible to filter by username. " You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/get-webvirtualdirectory?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for details.